# Proving syntactic ambiguity of type declaration grammar

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, logic, grammar, proof

Given a grammar to achieve C-style type declarations:

```
Declaration ::= Type Declarator ;

       Type ::= int | char

 Declarator ::= * Declarator

              | Declarator [ num ]

              | Declarator ( Type )

              | ( Declarator )

              | name
```

I must prove syntactic ambiguity. I am having difficulty identifying cases it which it is ambiguous. Here are all of the following cases I have come up with that satisfy the grammar:

- `int * Declarator;`
- `char * Declarator;`
- `int Declarator[num];`
- `char Declarator[num];`
- `int Declarator(type);`
- `char Declarator(type);`
- `int Declarator;`
- `char Declarator;`
- `int name;`
- `char name;`

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: `Declarator` is a non-terminal, just like `type`. You are not supposed to put `Declarator` in a string you want to analyze, you have to reduce it to a sequence of terminals.

Comment: What makes you think it is ambiguous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `int *something[3]` an array of three pointers or a pointer to an array of three ints? How about `int **something[3]`?

A simplified C grammar from the C standard's Appendix A includes:

```
(Many productions omitted)
declarator: pointeropt direct-declarator
pointer: '*'
       | '*' pointer
direct-declarator: identifier
                   '(' declarator ')'
                   direct-declarator '[' assignment-expressionopt ']'
```

How does that resolve the above ambiguity?

Also, consider the expression `*a[3]` and the declaration `int *a[3]`. In the expression, the postfix qualifier `[3]` takes precedence over the prefix qualifier `*`, which is the normal pattern for expressions. How does that compare with the syntax of the declaration? Why was that decision taken?